# Ignoring namespace in XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm using an xmlreader to read an xml file. The problem is i have many undefined namespaces in the child elements. Because of it, I'm unable to read the content of the files. Is there any way to read the contents of the files avoiding this issue or is there any solution to handle these kind of scenarios?

Comment: Can you post a small XML snippet to show your problem?

Comment: What do you mean that they're undefined? If there is really no namespace declaration for the given namespace prefixes, then you have garbage, and not XML.

Comment: Undefined in the sense, they arent defined in the root element but have been used in its descendants

Comment: Vote to close: so far there is no issue explained/shown in the question - provide sample XML, code, errors and expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the missing namespaces to the XmlReader like this.

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    NameTable = new NameTable(),
};
XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(settings.NameTable);
xmlns.AddNamespace("yourundeclarednamespace", "http://www.dummynamespace.org");
XmlParserContext context = new XmlParserContext(null, xmlns, "", XmlSpace.Default);
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, settings, context))
{
}
```